# Credentials work when connecting with SS Mangement Studio but I get this error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified in connection string

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string, publishing

I'm able to successfully connect to a database via the SSMS with some credentials.

```
Server name: 001.001.000.001
Login: user_name
Password: my_password
```

However, when I use the same credentials to connect to the same database in the connection string:

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=001.001.000.001;
           Initial Catalog=myAppDB;User ID=user_name;Password=my_password;
           Persist Security Info=True;" providerName="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1" />-->
```

I'm getting `error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified`. Is there any reason?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It could be a difference between how .NET and SQL Management Studio parse the server name. If the `001` is your real IP, have you tried removing the trailing zeros from the connection string?

Comment: So the intended IP address is `1.1.0.1` really, no need for the preceding 0 pads. - which IP address appears to be in China.

Comment: There's no zero in the real IP address.

Comment: Can u pls try using providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: replacing the providername with System.Data.SqlClient didn't solve the problem